# Not able to consume WEB API hosted in same server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Below web API returns JSON for the given ID.

http://aws-av-devser/Assigning_ID/api/QidMasters/2

It's working as expected in postman.

but when I try to consume this web API in different projects on the same server. I am getting
404 Not found Error

Below is the code to consume the web API

```
var uri = "http://aws-av-devser/Assigning_ID/api/QidMasters/2";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Error Message :

```
{
  StatusCode: 404, 
  ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', 
  Version: 1.1, 
  Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, 
  Headers:
  {
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2022 17:59:28 GMT
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
    Content-Length: 315
  }
}
```

Please correct me if I am missing something

Comment: You must be using a post request in postman

Comment: I am using Get request in the postman

Comment: do you send some security token in postman?

Comment: No, there is not security token. The Web API is working from different server. But when I try to consume the API which is hosted in same server, I am getting 404 error

Comment: Your api receive `get` or `post` request? 
Make sure to send the correct request type

Comment: After much investigation, I figured out, its because of internal domain issue.
The internal AWS server team using domain name. 
Thanks all for your updates on fixing this.